# Заменить все выражения в формате времени **:** в исходном тексте на формат (* ч. * мин.): на Pyton

Tags: python

Как заменить все выражения в формате времени **:** в исходном тексте на формат (* ч. * мин.): на Pyton

Answer (score 0):

Просто:

```py
import re
txt = input("Где поменять формат: ")
print(re.sub(r"(\d\d?):(\d\d)", r"\\1 ч. \\2 мин.", txt))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
txt = '22:15'.split(':')
print(f'{txt[0]} ч. {txt[1]} мин.')
```